# get only previous three values from the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am new to the python and pandas. Here , what I have is a dataframe which is like,

```
     Id     Offset       feature
   0        0              2
   0        5              2
   0        11             0
   0        21             22
   0        28             22
   1        32              0
   1        38             21
   1       42             21
   1        52             21
   1        55              0
   1        58              0
   1        62              1
   1        66              1
   1        70              1
   2        73              0
   2        78              1
   2        79              1
```

from this I am trying to get the previous three values from the column with the offsets of that .

SO, output would be like,

```
offset  Feature
11        2
21        22
28         22
// Here these three values are `of the 0 which is at 32 offset`

In the same dataframe for next place where is 0 

38        21
42        21 
52        21

58        0
62        1
66        1
```

is there any way through which I can get this ?
Thanks 
This will be on the basis of the document ID.

Comment: Do you need new column?

Comment: yes a new column.. will be needed or else I can have a new df anything

Comment: @jezrael is there any way for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Even i am quite new to pandas but i have attempted to answer you question.
I populated your data as comma separated values in data.csv and then used slicing to get the previous 3 columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./data.csv')
for index in (df.loc[df['Feature'] == 0]).index:
    print(df.loc[index-3:index-1])
```

The output looks like this. The leftmost column is index which you can discard if you dont want. Is this what you were looking for?

```
   Offset  Feature
2      11        2
3      21       22
4      28       22
   Offset  Feature
6      38       21
7      42       21
8      52       21
   Offset  Feature
7      42       21
8      52       21
9      55        0
    Offset  Feature
11      62        1
12      66        1
13      70        1
```

Note : There might be a more pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can take 3 previous rows of your current **0** value in the column using **loc**.

**Follow the code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("<path_of_the_file">)
zero_indexes = list(df[df['Feature'] == 0].index)
for each_zero_index in zero_indexes:
    df1 = df.loc[each_zero_index - 3: each_zero_index]
    print(df1) # This dataframe has 4 records. Your previous three including the zero record.
```

**Output:**

```
   Offset  Feature
2      11        2
3      21       22
4      28       22
5      32        0
   Offset  Feature
6      38       21
7      42       21
8      52       21
9      55        0
    Offset  Feature
7       42       21
8       52       21
9       55        0
10      58        0
    Offset  Feature
11      62        1
12      66        1
13      70        1
14      73        0
```